# Saving related products with extended controller

Tags: product, controllers

I have extended the controller `Catalog/ProductController.php` and I can't get related products to save when clicking the Save button.

Saving data on the attributes tab works as normal, but it's just the related products tab that isn't saving. (I'm only using 2 tabs.)

After clicking the save button, it redirects normally as if it worked and it says `The product has been saved.`

-

I have added a debug statement to the controller that I extend:

```
public function saveAction()
{
    print_r($_POST);exit;
    ...
}
```

which gave me this output:

```
Array
(
    [links] => Array
        (
            [related] => 
        )
)
```

So it looks like there aren't any related products being sent to the server-side.

-

Here are my files.

`app/code/local/NS1/MyModule/ManageComponentsController.php`

```
<?php
require_once 'Catalog/ProductController.php';

class NS1_MyModule_ManageComponentsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController
{
}
```

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/MyModule.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<adminhtml_managecomponents_grid>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_ComponentsGridForAttachComponents" name="admin.product.grid"/>
    </block>
</adminhtml_managecomponents_grid>

<adminhtml_managecomponents_new>
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="MyModule/adminhtml_catalog_product_edit" name="product_edit"></block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tabs" name="product_tabs"></block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="js">
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_js" template="catalog/product/js.phtml" name="catalog_product_js"></block>
        <block type="core/template" template="catalog/wysiwyg/js.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_managecomponents_new>

<adminhtml_managecomponents_edit>
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="MyModule/adminhtml_catalog_product_edit" name="product_edit"></block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="adminhtml/store_switcher" name="store_switcher" before="-"></block>
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tabs" name="product_tabs"></block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="js">
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_js" template="catalog/product/js.phtml" name="catalog_product_js"></block>
        <block type="core/template" name="catalog.wysiwyg.js" template="catalog/wysiwyg/js.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_managecomponents_edit>

<adminhtml_managecomponents_related>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_related" name="catalog.product.edit.tab.related"/>
        <block type="adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer" name="related_grid_serializer">
            <reference name="related_grid_serializer">
                <action method="initSerializerBlock">
                    <grid_block_name>catalog.product.edit.tab.related</grid_block_name>
                    <data_callback>getSelectedRelatedProducts</data_callback>
                    <hidden_input_name>links[related]</hidden_input_name>
                    <reload_param_name>products_related</reload_param_name>
                </action>
                <action method="addColumnInputName">
                    <input_name>position</input_name>
                </action>
            </reference>
        </block>
    </block>
</adminhtml_managecomponents_related>

<adminhtml_managecomponents_relatedgrid>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_related" name="catalog.product.edit.tab.related"/>
    </block>
</adminhtml_managecomponents_relatedgrid>

...
</layout>
```

`app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Related.php`

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Related extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    ...
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_link')->useRelatedLinks()
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->setProduct($this->_getProduct())
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', 9); // <------ added this line

    if ($this->isReadonly()) {
        $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
        if (empty($productIds)) {
            $productIds = array(0);
        }
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
    }

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
    ...
// Some columns have been commented out.
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    if (!$this->isReadonly()) {
        $this->addColumn('in_products', array(
            'header_css_class'  => 'a-center',
            'type'              => 'checkbox',
            'name'              => 'in_products',
            'values'            => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
            'align'             => 'center',
            'index'             => 'entity_id'
        ));
    }

    $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('ID'),
        'sortable'  => true,
        'width'     => 60,
        'index'     => 'entity_id'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Component Name'),
        'index'     => 'name'
    ));

    /*
    $this->addColumn('type', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Type'),
        'width'     => 100,
        'index'     => 'type_id',
        'type'      => 'options',
        'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_type')->getOptionArray(),
    ));

    $sets = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')
        ->setEntityTypeFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId())
        ->load()
        ->toOptionHash();

    $this->addColumn('set_name', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Attrib. Set Name'),
        'width'     => 130,
        'index'     => 'attribute_set_id',
        'type'      => 'options',
        'options'   => $sets,
    ));
    */

    $this->addColumn('status', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Status'),
        'width'     => 90,
        'index'     => 'status',
        'type'      => 'options',
        'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->getOptionArray(),
    ));

    $this->addColumn('visibility', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Visibility'),
        'width'     => 90,
        'index'     => 'visibility',
        'type'      => 'options',
        'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getOptionArray(),
    ));

    $this->addColumn('sku', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('SKU'),
        'width'     => 80,
        'index'     => 'sku'
    ));

    /*
    $this->addColumn('price', array(
        'header'        => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Price'),
        'type'          => 'currency',
        'currency_code' => (string) Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE),
        'index'         => 'price'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('position', array(
        'header'            => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Position'),
        'name'              => 'position',
        'type'              => 'number',
        'validate_class'    => 'validate-number',
        'index'             => 'position',
        'width'             => 60,
        'editable'          => !$this->_getProduct()->getRelatedReadonly(),
        'edit_only'         => !$this->_getProduct()->getId()
    ));
    */

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
...
}
```

Comment: Hard to say without being able to see any of your code and/or being able to replicate your issue.

Comment: Hey, I have now posted my code in the question.

Comment: I have found out that the related products are not saving when the position column is commented out.

Comment: I have now solved the problem woo! I kept the 'position' column in PHP, and hid the column with CSS - I'll post my CSS solution in my question. I guess some JavaScript code required the column to be there.

Comment: Nice, if you were able to solve it you should post an answer to your own question and accept! Funny how reading back over things can make the answer jump out sometimes isn't it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now solved this problem.

The issue was that the 'position' column needed to be in the grid.

So I kept the call to addColumn() for the 'position' column, and hid the column with CSS:

```
#related_product_grid_table th:last-child,
#related_product_grid_table td:last-child
{
    display: none;
}
```